# Fragment Hide and show on click

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, fragmenttransaction, fragmentmanager

I have a fragment that needs to be updated from the activity continuously and I only want to show this fragment when I click on a button,on click of the same button the fragment should be hidden but still be active so I can update contents of the fragment from the activity (the fragment contains a recycler view).
While hiding and showing this fragment I would like to animate the transaction.

**

### Working Code

**

Activity XML (the frame layout that contains the fragment)

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <fragment
            android:name="octave.foodster.fragment_cart"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_cart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

The java code in the activity (i removed the animation for now)

```
        @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
        case R.id.cart:
            Log.i("click", "menu");

            showHideFragment(fragment);
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void showHideFragment(final Fragment fragment) {

    final FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_slide_from_right, R.anim.animation_leave);

    if (fragment.isHidden()) {
        fragTransaction.show(fragment);
        Log.d("hidden", "Show");
    } else {
        fragTransaction.hide(fragment);
        Log.d("Shown", "Hide");
    }

    fragTransaction.commit();
}
```

And in the activities onCreate()--this is done to hide the fragment by default

```
fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_cart);
    final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.hide(fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Maybe you can try a dialog fragment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow this function in an `onClick` function to do show hide of fragment on clicking a button:

```
// Call this function inside onClick of button

public void showHideFragment(final Fragment fragment){

    FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in,
                    android.R.animator.fade_out);

    if (fragment.isHidden()) {
        fragTransaction.show(fragment);
        Log.d("hidden","Show");
    } else {
        fragTransaction.hide(fragment);
        Log.d("Shown","Hide");                        
    }

    fragTransaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: it would be great if you could also provide the XML for the activity (should i use a fragment or a frame layout?) and the initialization of the fragment .

Comment: Use  fragment. You must have already define it. Use it as usual when define  a fragment and button in an activity or another fragment. I believe either way works

Comment: U can refer this link also  : http://www.coderzheaven.com/2013/06/05/hide-show-fragment-animation-android-retain-state-fragment-android/

Comment: i updated the question to add my current code,it's almost there but the fragment is visible by default.How can I hide on default?

Comment: use a flag and define fragTransaction.hide(fragment);

Comment: yep that worked,although it seems a little unconventional.

Comment: U can try like this also-      FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();    use this step before function calling and define this fragtransaction in the showhidefragment function.